# Is there a site somewhere that shows examples of all HTML4 objects?

Tags: html, javascript, html5

Is there a site somewhere that shows examples of all HTML4 objects?   Basically, I want to create a library of automated browser tests but I need a site (preferrably 100% HTML4 and basic Javascript and/or CSS).

Does such a thing already exist so I don't need to code it myself?

Things that I hope the site would contain: examples of textfields, forms, tables, iframes, styles, dropdowns, date widgets, radio buttons, checkboxes, window popups, layers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually used was this one:

http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/